# Getting derivative by "sympy"

Tags: sympy, derivative

I am trying to get the derivative of a equation.

I found a library named "sympy" can do this, however, I kept getting error while using this.

This is my code:

```
from sympy import *

x = symbols('x')

diff(cos(x), x)
```

This is the error:

```
importing sympy.geometry.util with 'from sympy import *' has been
deprecated since SymPy 1.6. Use import sympy.geometry.util instead.
See https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/18245 for more info.
  self.Warn(
```

I try to replace 'from sympy import *' with 'import sympy.geometry.util' but still doesn't work.

This is the error after I replace:

```
importing sympy.geometry.util with 'from sympy import *' has been
deprecated since SymPy 1.6. Use import sympy.geometry.util instead.
See https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/18245 for more info.
  self.Warn(
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: When you replace that, what error do you get? \

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this but the error is only a warning so you can ignore it.

Comment: Maybe try upgrade your version to 1.6.1 or 1.6.2 if you don't want to see the error.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run your code on my compiler. It is working fine.

Try reinstalling 'sympy'

[image: I am getting the answer]